# How to validate inputs with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to validate inputs with javascript, without using the `required` or `max-length` or `min-lenght` property this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>                 
 <html>                                          
  <head>                                                
   <title>Reset your password</title>                   
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images.jpeg"/>     
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>                                                 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>                                                 
  </head>                       
  <body>                                                                             
   <center><form method="POST" id="form" action="/sucess">
   <h1>Reset your password</h1>                         
   <p id="warning_1"><b>Warning:</b> Passwords longer than 16 characters <br>cannot be used with the Xbox 360</p>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Adress">
   <div class="fill_field" id="fill_field_1">            
    <p>Please fill out this field</p>
   </div>
   <div class="minium_8_characters" id="minium_8_characters_1">
    <p>Minium 8 characters</p>
   </div>                                               
   <div class="cant_contain_space" id="cant_contain_sp
ace_1">
    <p>Can't contain space</p>
   </div>                                               
   <input type="password" name="old_password" id="old_password" placeholder="Old password">                                                  
   <i></i>                                              
   <div class="fill_field" id="fill_field_2">            
    <p>Please fill out this field</p>       
   </div>
   <div class="minium_8_characters" id="minium_8_characters_2">                                               
    <p>Minium 8 characters</p>                          
   </div>                                               
   <div class="cant_contain_space" id="cant_contain_space_2">                                                 
    <p>Can't contain space</p>                          
   </div>                                               
   <input type="password" id="new_password" placeholder="New password">                  
   <i></i>                                              
   <div class="fill_field" id="fill_field_3">
    <p>Please fill out this field</p>                   
   </div>
   <div class="minium_8_characters" id="minium_8_characters_3">
    <p>Minium 8 characters</p>
   </div>
   <div class="cant_contain_space" id="cant_contain_space_3">
    <p>Can't contain space</p>
   </div>
   <p id="warning_2">8-character minimum; case sensitive</p>
   <input type="password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Reenter password">
   <i></i>
   <div class="fill_field" id="fill_field_4">
    <p>Please fill out this field</p>
   </div>
   <div class="minium_8_characters" id="minium_8_characters_4">
    <p>Minium 8 characters</p>
   </div>
   <div class="cant_contain_space" id="cant_contain_space_4">
   <p>Can't contain space</p>
  </div>
  <div id="error">
   <p>Password did not match</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="validate()">Next</button>
  </form></center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Css code:

```
*{                                                   
 margin:0;
 padding:0;                                           
}                                                                                                         

@font-face {                                          
 font-family: Mundo Sans Std Light;     
 src: url(./mundo_sans_std_light.otf)                
}
                                                 
#form{                                               
 width:80%;                                           
 position:absolute;                                   
 top:40%;
 left:50%;                                            
 transform: translate(-50%,-40%);                     
}  
                                                                                    
label{                                               
 font-size:19pt;
 color:#9a9a9a;                                       
 padding-left:19px;                                   
 padding-top:5px;
}  
                                                                                                   
h1{
 color:#5d5a67;                                       
 font-size:28pt;                                      
 /*margin-top:100px;*/
 font-family: Mundo Sans Std Light;
}                             
                                                                        
#warning_1 {                                         
 font-size:14pt;
 margin-top:30px;
}

input {
 display:block;
 width:50%;
 height:27px;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding-left:5px;
 border:2px solid #a0a0a0;
 outline:none;
}

#old_password{
 margin:0;
 margin-top:15px;
}

input:focus{
 border:2.5px solid #0971de;
}

#warning_2{
 color:#1C1C1C;                                       
 font-size:10.5pt;                                    
 padding-top:15px;
}

.fill_field {                                        
 display:none;
 width:50%;
 height:27px;
 margin-top:30px;
 border:2px solid transparent;
}

.fill_field p{
 padding-top:2.5px;
 text-align:left;
 color:#ff4040;
}

.minium_8_characters{
 display:none;                                        
 width:50%;                                           
 height:27px;
 margin-top:15px;
 border:2px solid transparent;
}

.minium_8_characters p{
 padding-top:2.5px;
 text-align:left;
 color:#ff4040;
}

.cant_contain_space {
 display:none;
 width:50%;
 height:27px;
 margin-top:15px;
 border:2px solid transparent;
}

.cant_contain_space p{                               
 padding-top:2.5px;
 text-align:left;
 color:#ff4040;
}

#error{
 display:none;
 width:50%;
 height:27px;
 margin-top:30px;
 border:2px solid transparent;
}

#error p{
 padding-top:2.5px;
 text-align:left;
 color:#ff4040;
}

button{
 width:220px;
 height:30px;
 border:0;
 margin-top:60px;
 color:black;
 background:#c8c8c8;
}
```

What I need?

So guys, I want when an input is empty the `fill_field` div has a display block, and when an input has less than 8 characters, the `minium_8_characters` div has a display block and if the input has space the div `cant_contain_space` now have display block, and if the input has more than 8 characters unless it has space, the display of these divs must be none, I want to validate all these inputs with javascript, but I can't do this, I'm 1 week away with this problem and I can't solve it at all.  And the button is of type Button and not submit because the function of submitting the form I created with javascript, but it lacks the function to validate, how can I do this validation without having to write a thousand lines of code?

**Note:** Notice that for each input I put a different id on the divs I mentioned above.

Comment: You can use a library like https://validatejs.org/ or https://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

JS:

```
function validateMe() {
  let input = document.forms["formName"]["name"].value;
  if (input == "") {
    // YOU HANDLE CODE FOR INVALID CASE GOES HERE
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="formName" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateMe()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, but how could I check the input empty or with space or with less than 8 characters?  remembering that in addition to checking I need that if input 2 is empty the display of the div `fill_field_2` is block, now if input 2 has one or more characters and less than 8 I need the display of the div `minium_8_characters` to be block , I need to do this validation for all fields

Comment: check is empty or spaces : 

function check(yourString){
    return yourString=== null || yourString.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
}

Check number of character:

if(yourString.value.length < 8){
return false;
}

After you got a combination of checking result you can handle everything you want by handling logic and display UI via JS